# Starting of laravel in windows

Tags: php, laravel

I have recently started using laravel
I have searched a lot and found many help how to start a project in laravel.

I am using windows 64bit and xampp
As per the guide from [Larvel](https://laravel.com/) and [Turtorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/) I have figured out how to start using laravel.

Fisrt Install `composer` then install `laravel` and then create a project
I have first installed composer using **composer-install.exe** which is available in laravel site.
I run that setup and installed it in `C://xampp/php/php.exe`.
Then I run the code `composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel` on the location `C://xampp/htdocs`
I got the project installed successfully.....  **:)**
[image]

Then i run it in local host by the following code `php artisan serve`

It gave me an localhost link which lead me too:

[image]
It was according to the instructions from tutorialspoint.
 But there Laravel was not like this.(not a matter)
 
And when i searched further i cant understand anything.

They have completely different files(some) and the codes are very different.

**Please someone guide me how to do an "Hello World" Example in it.**
Thanks 
**And i found `app/HTTP/routes.php` missing! Please find it also.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/structure) would be a good reference for you.

According to Laravel, you can define your routes inside `web.php` file under `routes\web.php` folder

Your views would be under `resources\views` folder

Create a controller using command line.
`php artisan make:controller Welcome`

Edit your controller file and edit the generated code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class Welcome extends Controller
{
    //

    public function index() {
      $data = array('name'=>'Conor');
      return view('hello',$data);
    }
}
```

Create a view manually if not present inside `resources\views\hello.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello <?php echo $name; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Hello <?php echo $name;?></h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit `App\routes\web.php` and add the following code `Route::get('/welcome', 'Welcome@index');`

Now run `php artisan serve`

Comment: I cannot find `routes.php` on `App/Http` folder

Comment: How's that possible? Can you try to create it and add Route::get('/', 'Welcome@index'); code? Here Welcome is your controller and index is your function name

Comment: I have added `routes.php` and `Route::get('/', 'Welcome@index');` to it.Now what?. [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/cgerm3)

Comment: Did you create `Welcome` controller with `index` function before that?

Comment: Please explain what to do?

Comment: Edited the code. Apologies! I guess since version 5.3 the routes are written inside `routes\web.php`

Comment: For your information there is no folder as `App/routes` either.[look like this](http://prntscr.com/cgezyw)

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I got a bad keyboard. It's `routes\web.php` inside your app root

Comment: Oh yes there is. Thanks bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123064/discussion-between-conor-and-sanketr).